# What is $W_n ?$

Tags: notation

I'm trying to solve an equation for B where

> $2 B e^{(1-B)}=1$

I plugged it into [wolfram alpha and got](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*B*e%5E%281-B%29%3D1):

[image]

What is that $W_n$ mean? How do I intrepret this answer?

(Feel free to retag it, I wasn't entirely sure what it falls under!)

Comment: Isn't there a tiny box that says "W_k is the analytic continuation of the product log function" with a link to some documentation there? ( http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html )

Comment: Lambert W function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html.

Comment: @Myself nope, it just mentions Z being integers.

Comment: @Sivaram are you saying that B is a set of values, not a particular solvable value?

Comment: @glowcoder: The value is negative of the Lambert W Function evaluated at $\frac{-1}{2e}$.

Comment: Actually this is a dupe: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10261/inverse-of-y-xex. +1 though, it would have been hard to find that out without knowing the name in the first place!

Comment: There are two real solutions and infinite complex solutions.

Comment: @Moron - Perhaps in one sense, but the two questions are approached in a very different manner.

Comment: @glowcode: You _are_ trying to invert $xe^{-x}$, so looks the same to me. Anyway, we need 4 more votes...

Comment: @Moron that's merely the follow up. My REAL question is "What is W sub n" - the answer to that is, apparently, the Lambert W function. It would be like if I said "I want to reverse a string, and someone told me to use recursion. What is recursion?" and someone said "That's a duplicate of 'how to reverse a string'" The driving force behind the question is the terminology, not the math.

Comment: @glow: Don't agree with the analogy, but do agree that this is a terminology question and is technically not a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$W(z)$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

$W_k(-\frac{1}{2e})$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ denotes the $k^{th}$ root of the equation $xe^x = -\frac{1}{2e}$

[image]

Comment: The text in that image is hardly readable on my browser... Why not just include a short writeup? +1 Anyway :-)

Comment: @Moron it was great for me when I clicked on the image to snap it to a better resolution. @Sivaram that's so weird, I can't get that output to come up. It would appear my result is .23 and 2.67 - Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Moron: Added. I think the image will be better if you try opening the image on a new tab.

Comment: What is a new tab? Just kidding :-) In any case, you _need_ some supporting write up. I am pretty sure glowcoder could see the same thing before even creating this question :-)