# How can I solve $x^x = 5$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is $x^x=y$ solvable for $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x)

I've been playing with this equation for a while now and can't figure out how to isolate $x$.

I've gotten to $x \ln x = \ln 5$, which seems like it would be easier to work with, but I can't figure out where to go from there.

Is it possible to solve this algebraically? If not, how can I find the value of $x$?

Comment: @J.M. Definitely. I figured it was asked before, but couldn't fathom how to search for it.

Comment: In adition to the answers: a quick numeric solution can be obtained iteratively via $x=5^{1/x}$. Or, more quick: $x= \sqrt{x \, 5^{1/x}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can find the result using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Let's define $y\,e^y=t$.  Then   $y=W(t)$   where $W(t)$  is the Lambert W function.

$$x=e^y\Rightarrow x^x= (e^y)^{e^y}=e^{y\,e^y}=5$$

$$\log e^{y\,e^y}=\log 5$$

$$y\,e^y\log e=y\,e^y=\log 5$$

Thus, $t=\log 5$,  and  from my first definition $y=W(\log 5)$, so $x=e^y=e^{W(\log 5)}$.

It can be expressed in another way too.

$$xy=y\,e^y=t=\log 5$$

$$x=\frac{\log 5}{y}=\frac{\log 5}{W(\log 5)}$$

I [asked](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28log%285%29%29/%28ProductLog%28log%285%29%29%29&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_%2aMath-) Wolfram Alpha what the numerical value is, and it said $x\approx2.129372$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to solve this algebraically.

Look at [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  In your case, the solution is $x=\frac{\ln(5)}{W(\ln(5))}$.