# Solving $x^y + y^x = a$

Tags: cryptography

If $a$ is given how can I calculate $x^y$ and $y^x$ the fastest way? Is there any other way than brute forcing? How is this type of equation called?

Let's say $x$ and $y$ must be $>1$ and non negative integers.

Comment: are $x,y$ and $a$ integers ? rationals ? nonnegative integers ?

Comment: $$x^y=e^{y \ln x},\,y^x=e^{x \ln y}$$

Comment: This equation may have 0, 1, >1 or $\infty$ solutions, depending on its parameters...

Comment: They can be any type of number, but I think it's harder when you try to find non negative integers for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How about $x=1$, $y=a-1$?

Comment: @user7530 ok I see, thanks. But If we say $x$ and $y$ must be each $>1$?

Comment: I don't think there's any hope for any kind of efficient solution. This seems at least as hard as the discrete log problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze this a bit, assuming that $x \le y$:

- For $x = 2$, you need to test $y = 2, 3, \dots, \lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor$.
- For $x = 3$, you need to test $y = 3, 4, \dots, \lfloor \log_3 a \rfloor$.

  ...
- The last $x$ is the biggest one for which $x^x \le a$. For example, for $a = 2^{64}$ (the first nonnegative integer number that fits in 64 bits), that's $x = 16$.

So, let $a = 2^{64}-1$. Then, we have $246$ candidates for a solution:

\begin{align*}
&x = 2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{2,3,\dots,63\}, \\
&x = 3 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{3,4,\dots,40\}, \\
&x = 4 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{4,5,\dots,31\}, \\
&x = 5 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{5,6,\dots,27\}, \\
&x = 6 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{6,7,\dots,24\}, \\
&x = 7 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{7,8,\dots,22\}, \\
&x = 8 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{8,9,\dots,21\}, \\
&x = 9 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{9,10,\dots,20\}, \\
&x = 10 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{10,11,\dots,19\}, \\
&x = 11 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{11,12,\dots,18\}, \\
&x = 12 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{12,13,\dots,17\}, \\
&x = 13 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{13,14,\dots,17\}, \\
&x = 14 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{14,15,16\}, \\
&x = 15 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y \in \{16\},
\end{align*}

I draw two conclusions from here:

1. Bruteforcing is simple.
2. Only a negligible number of these systems ($246$ among the first $2^{64}-1$) have solutions.

It's easier to go through all possible $(x,y)$, construct all $246$ values of $(x,y,a)$, put them in a file or a database, and just search for a solution when one is needed (and, most likely, doesn't exist).

The larger your numbers are, the less likely it is that you'll have a solution for any given $a$, so there is no point in going beyond $64$ bit (actually, there is no point going even that far).

Comment: Very good, very understandable. Thank you! Hvala Vedrane! ;)

Comment: @arminb I'm glad I could help. Drago mi je da sam mogao pomoći. :-)

Comment: I have a follow up question. How to find out $x$ for $x^x \le a$ the fastest way?

Comment: Given the speed of growth of such function, a simple `while` loop in any language will be very quick. For example, Mathematica on my computer (3+ years old) finds a solution for $$a = 2^{100000} - 1 = 2^{10^5} - 1$$ in about 3 seconds (it's $x \le 7740$). Notice that this number needs $10^5$ bits, i.e., around 12.5KiB of memory, so the arithmetic operations are quite slow (they need to be software-simulated, as the processor doesn't support that).

Comment: At the moment, I have no idea how to do it without the aid of computer, apart from some numerical methods (bisection and likes), which would be too slow to do by hand (just try getting $7740^{7740}$ by hand ;-)).

Comment: Yes, trying each $x^x$ in a while loop is one possibility. But I hoped there was a more elegant way to obtain $x$.

Comment: That's a bit subjective. For me, simple `while` is elegant. If you prefer Lambert W function, check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/).