# Solving $x$ for $y = x^x$ using a normal scientific calculator (no native Lambert W function)?

Tags: exponentiation, calculator

Solving $x$ for $y = x^x$ using *Lambert W function* is clear enough [thanks to this handy answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54217/93523), but as I'm using the solution in a network support document I need it in a form that can be solved on a normal scientific calculator (assume **y** is a positive integer). People using the document or perhaps embedding the equation in a script might not have real-time access to *WolframAlpha*.

**So my question is:** *Can $x$ be solved for $y = x^x$ using only the buttons provided on a normal scientific calculator? If so, how?*

$$x=\frac{\ln(y)}{W(\ln y)}= ???$$

---

A photo of a primitive calculator caught in the wild:

[image]

<sub>(Incidentally, has anyone else ever read "WolframAlpha" and been reminded of "[Wolfram & Hart](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Wolfram_&_Hart)"?)</sub>

Comment: Use bisection. ${}{}$

Comment: I've never misread WolframAlpha (or I have always done so and I'm not aware of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of my sanity, let's assume $y>1$ to avoid branches and multiple possible answers for $x$.

Applying Newton's method, we have

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{y(x_n)^{-x_n}-1}{\ln(x_n)+1}$$

For example, take $y=2$, $x_0=1.5$,

$x_1=1.5+\frac{2(1.5)^{-1.5}-1}{\ln(1.5)+1}=1.56308382$

$x_2=x_1+\frac{2(x_1)^{-x_1}-1}{\ln(x_1)+1}=1.559621837$

$x_3=1.55961047$

Thus, the solution to $2=x^x$ is $x\approx1.55961047$.