# How to solve an equation with a single and nested ln

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Given following equation $1444 = ln(p) * ln(ln(p))$. How do I solve this equation for p? I found (through WolframAlpha) that $p$ should be equal to $6.29*10^{112}$, but I can't seem to find a way to find this result algebraically.

Comment: There is no such way. You need numerical methods or the Lambert-W-function.

Comment: I think you need numerical methods to find it

Comment: Let $x=\ln p$ then you have $1444=\ln x^x$. Now check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x

Comment: Thanks! I already suspected that there's no obvious way to solve this. Thank you :)