# Solving $ax=e^{bx}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, inverse-function

I've been asked by a friend to help him solve this equation, but since we couldn't find the right answer, I thought about posting it here.
Firstly, I thought about derivating both sides and get:

$a=be^{bx}$

and from here we could find the answer pretty quickly, but then I noticed that what I did was incorrect because I can't derivate both sides - the functions aren't equal.

Comment: Firstly, you can't differentiate both sides of an equation.

Comment: Secondly, it is a transcendental equation, which means that you cannot solve it analytically in elementary functions.

Comment: You can either use [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) for an exact form of the solution or [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) for an approximate solution.

Comment: $f(x)=g(x)$ for some number $x$ does not imply that $f'(x)=g'(x)$. For example, for $x=1$ we have $x^2=x$ but not $2x=1$.  
You can differentiate respect to some variable $x$ both sides of an equality when the equality holds for every value of $x$ (or, at least, for every value in some neighbourhood, and the equality of the derivatives will hold in this neighbourhood).

Comment: :-( Fairly certain there is a good duplicate out there, but I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

By the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we have,

$$ax=e^{bx}$$

$$xe^{-bx}=\frac1a$$

$$-bxe^{-bx}=-\frac ba$$

$$-bx=W\left(-\frac ba\right)$$

> $$x=-\frac1bW\left(-\frac ba\right)$$

If $0<b/a<e^{-1}$, then there will be two real solutions, denoted by the two branches of the Lambert W function.

If $b/a<0$, then there is only one real solution.

If $b=0$, then the solution is $x=\frac1a$.

If $b/a=e^{-1}$, then $x=\frac1b$.

If $b/a>e^{-1}$, then there are no real solutions.

---

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187145/lambert-w-function-aproximation/2187158#2187158) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2190032/272831) for some basic approximations.

I also made a quick approximation calculator-ish thing for the Lambert W function:

[Desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pggygcaf4c)

$f(x)$ works best for large inputs and $g(x)$ works best for inputs close to zero.

Comment: The x=1/b solution is wrong. Substituting that value for x I get a/b = e, which is not the same as b/a = e^(1/e).

Comment: @TMM Sorry, I forgot my special values.  It should've been $e^{-1}$, not $e^{1/e}$.

Comment: @TMM Clearly fixed: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rhp1tz9vo8